# Asymptotic notation of 4(n/2)^3

Tags: time-complexity

Question has been updated..Please ,Look at the updated (last paragraph) section...

I am working on my own algorithm and trying to analyze the time complexity of it.FYI, I am not a CS student and I know a little bit about calculating time complexity. However, I am having trouble finding the time complexity of one of the while loop in my algorithm. So, I cannot do the further analysis because I am stuck on that. Can someone tell me the time complexity of the following loop? It would be a big help.
Thank you.

```
// max_ value is changed according to user input,but it should be a an even number

int i=1,j=1,c=0;

while(i<max_)
{
    if(j==max_-1)
    {
        j = -1;
        int v = ((max_-4)/2)+1;
        if(c>=(v*(v+2)))
        {
            i+=2;
            c = -1;
        }
    }
    c++;
    j+=2;

}
```

Note: max_ value is changed according to user input,but it should be a an even number.

Updated-------

Finally,I could calculated the time complexity of above loop.
Which is (n/2)^3 .time complexity of whole algorithm which is T = 4(n/2)^3  .now could you tell me what is the asymptotic notation of 4(n/2)^3 ?

Comment: Isn't the complexity just `O(n)`? It's a single loop, you never change `max_`, so it seems like a linear relation.

Comment: max_ value  is changed according to user input,but it should be a an even number @VLAZ

Comment: Let's say every assignment (=) costs 1 time unit. Now for i = 2, how many time units do you need? How many do you need for i = 3, i = 4? Now how's the relation between time units and i?

Comment: I am sorry.I am a bit confused about the question.could you explain it more? @JonasWilms